# Don't fail if log files are unavailable

Tags: python, django, logging

I have a Django application deployed to some server. Due to some mysterious reason, the permissions on one of the log files changes and Django can no longer write to it. The result is that Django refuses to start up, and uWSGI returns 'internal server errors' all the time.

How can I tell the Python RotatingFileHandler not to fail if it can't write to a log file? Best case would be to try another file or path, but a good enough fallback would be to simply not log to this particular file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of `logging.raiseExceptions`. This is set to `True` by default, as that's what you want for development and test environments. If you set it to `False`, which is normally what you want for production environments, then logging errors should be silently ignored (swallowed). See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.handleError) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

check for `ps aux | grep 'uwsgi'`. Give permission to corresponding user.

```
sudo chown <user> <logfile>
```